# Where is the sbt cached resolution stored?

Tags: scala, sbt

According to [1], project reloads should be sped up by adding

```scala
ThisBuild / updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(true)
```

To the `build.sbt`.

I've done that, and now I want to inspect these cached results (basically to confirm that the setting is active and actually works).

I have looked at the mentioned folder (`$HOME/.sbt/1.0/dependency`), but there is nothing at that location.

If I start sbt shell and do `print dependencyCacheDirectory`, it lists that folder for each of the sbt modules (I have a multi-module project, with about 200 modules :) ):

```
> print dependencyCacheDirectory
...
dependencyCacheDirectory
    /Users/jml/.sbt/1.0/dependency
```

Using sbt version 1.8.0 (project sbt version 1.7.2), IntellIJ 2022.3 with 'use sbt shell for project reloads and builds', and custom launcher pointing to my 1.8.0 sbt-launch-jar).

[1] - https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cached-Resolution.html#Cached+Resolution

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this feature is only used when using Ivy, and it has no effect when using Coursier (which is the default nowadays).